# Compare two cells and if the values match, fill in another cell with specified values

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a code where if a value in column "E" is an exact match to a value in column "E", then insert "5078" in the respective cell in column A and "service fee" in the respective cell in column "c". 
so For example:

[image]

Comment: correction:  *if a value in column "D" is an exact match to a value in column "E",...

Comment: Shouldn't the values in column `A` containing the negative values in column `D` also be overwritten? You can improve your question using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62378639/edit) button below your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i have interpreted your question correctly, if the value in `C` matches any value found in `D` then overwrite the value in `A` with `5078` and insert 
`Service Fee` in `B`.  If the value in `Cn` + `Cn+1` = 0 then it simply adds `service fee` in `b`  else it does nothing.  If so the below works.

```
    Sub Mblm() 'the Mblm can be changed to whatever you want.

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'Means people cant see this running through, it just appears

Dim x As Long, rCount As Long
Dim cell As Range

rCount = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
'This counts the rows in column "C"

    For x = 2 To rCount Step 1 'started at 2 presuming you have a header.
    'This is a loop, it counts up by 1 until it gets to the row count then it stops.

        Set cell = Sheet1.Range("D2:D" & rCount).Find(What:=Sheet1.Range("C" & x).Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
       'this is searching in column "d" it will only search as far as max rows in column "c" and it searches for what value we are on for "c"
        If cell Is Nothing Then
       'If there is no match it adds only service fee
        If Sheet1.Range("C" & x).Value + Sheet1.Range("C" & x + 1).Value = 0 Then
        Sheet1.Range("B" & x).Value = "Service Fee"
        End If
        Else
       'If there is a match we want the below adding.
        Sheet1.Range("A" & x).Value = "5078"
        Sheet1.Range("B" & x).Value = "Service Fee"
        End If
    Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

If you add this in to VBA and push `F8` you will see it step through the code.

Note i wrote this in `thisworkbook`

Snapshot showing end result. Hope this helps. :)
[image]

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for answering my question. So the value in Column  C and D won't be in the same row. I need it to search column D for matching values and if there is a match then fill in Column A and B. Think of Colum D as a separate table. Also, there won't be an exact match for all values in Colum C, in which case I want the values in those cells left as is. In the table, all the negative values have a match in each column, but different rows. @StevenByrne

Comment: No problem @Mblm i have revised the answer as per your comment.

Comment: This is awesome! One more question, can we add just "Service Fee" to the positive values as well in Column B. The idea is that this is a debit and a credit of service fees so the positive and negative values are related. I am just trying to differentiate d/t types of payments. Thank you again.

Comment: @Mblm sure, updated.  Let me know if you need anything further or if I can explain it further. :-)

Comment: Hi again, the only issue I have now is that the service fee is populated to other transactions in the table. Beyond what I showed you here the table has other types of transactions not related to service fees. is there a way to limit it?

Comment: Sure, or if you can advise how it would know we could add in another variable to stop it. i.e. does the -70 always appear straight after the +70? Or is there another way to differentiate this to the other lines, do the other lines have text in column b alread?

Comment: yes, all the negative values come after the positive values. unfortunately, some of the other lines will have empty cells.

Comment: Is there ever a chance a negative value may not be a service fee?

Comment: Okay, on that basis i have revised the formula.  If you are happy with it, please can you accept it as an answer and uprate it if you think i have been helpful.  Thank you.

Comment: You were more than helpful, you did a fantastic job! Thank you so much for answering my question. This will make my job so much easier!